# Can't have seen vs. Couldn't see

Tags: periphrastic-modals

I know that can't have pp refers to past and couldn't also refers to past. So what is the difference between them in the following examples.

> 1: *You **can't have seen** that film last week. It was only released yesterday.*

> 2: *You **couldn't see** that film last week. It was only released yesterday.*

Comment: Note that there's also #3 *You **couldn't have seen** that film last week...* The *nuance* of difference is that #1 puts the focus on *time of speaking*, which means it's the more likely choice if you're refuting someone who *currently* claims he *did* see it last week. If you were just talking more generally about what was or wasn't possible last week, you'd use #2 or #3 (where arguably #3 more strongly puts the focus in the past). But these are very fine nuances that normally wouldn't be either intended or understood. For most purposes, they're just different ways of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 1 means "Your claim that you saw the film last week is impossible."

Sentence 2 means "Last week it was not possible (for you) to see that film."

So the first sentence is necessarily about a claim that "you" made, while the second sentence could be in reference to a claim made, or it could just be a fact about last week, in a similar sense to this:

> Before COVID, you couldn't wear a mask in public without getting funny looks.

Note that this last sentence is just a fact about the time before COVID, not contradicting anybody's claim. The same sentence with "*...you couldn't have worn...*" would be contradicting a claim.